# Redirect stdin to stdout while waiting for background process

Tags: bash

I have the following code:

```
cmd cmd_args & WAIT_PID=$!

trap "kill -s SIGTERM $WAIT_PID" SIGTERM SIGINT SIGKILL

wait $WAIT_PID
```

With this I want to be able to kill any background process whenever someone tries to kill this script.  However, I still want stdin to be redirected to the background process, which is not happening.

I would like to grab wait's stdin and redirect it to the background process. For that, I've tried:

```
wait $WAIT_PID 0>&1 1> named_pipe
```

But without any luck.

Comment: FYI, you can't trap `SIGKILL`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you can't trap `SIGKILL` (or `SIGSTOP`).

Other than that, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd cmd_args <&0 &
wait_pid=$!
trap "kill -s SIGTERM $wait_pid" SIGTERM SIGINT
wait $wait_pid
```

The `<&0` will tell bash that you want `cmd`'s stdin to be the script's stdin.

Slightly off topic, but another interesting method of dumping bytes into a running process' stdin is to send them directly to it's `/proc` file descriptor, as in:

```
echo "Stuff to send to the process" >/proc/$wait_pid/fd/0
```

Comment: I've tried your solution and it doesn't work. Isn't `<&0` the same as `0<&0`? Does it have any effect at all?

Comment: It's the same as `0<&0` and yes, it does have an effect if you background the command. Without it, the backgrounded command will not read from the script's stdin. As for it not working for you, try the above script with `cat <&0 &` as the command, then start typing random lines. You will notice the lines are duplicated by `cat`, proving that it reads (as intended) from stdin. You can also try it without the `<&0` to see the difference.